# jQuery Isotope — sort by category, but specify which comes first

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm looking for a type of sort behaviour, one that would match a *specific* category and bring this to the front of the listing. Like a filter would, except without removing other items.

Imagine these category items in an Isotope grid:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Red
- Green
- Blue

If I sort by category, it does so alphabetically to show:

- Blue
- Blue
- Green
- Green
- Red
- Red

What I'd like is to float a **specific** category to the front, e.g. "Green", like so:

- Green
- Green
- Red
- Red
- Blue
- Blue

Is this possible?

I've tried adding a `getSortData` function for each category like so:

```
      green : function( $elem ) {
        var $greenItems = $elem.filter('.green');            
        var $otherItems = $elem.filter(':not(.green)');
        return $greenItems.add($otherItems);
      }
      // repeat for blue, red, etc
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
green : function( $elem ) {
    var isGreen = $elem.hasClass('green');
    return (!isGreen?' ':'');
},
// etc
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yvk9q/9/