# Sorting Dynamic Data with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I am trying to use [Isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to sort data by type. There seem to be a few ways to do this however they all require that you know the sort variables before hand.

One of the best examples of what I'm talking about is found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551662/jquery-isotope-sort-by-category-but-specify-which-comes-first).

In the example they are trying to sort by class for example group all elements with class `.milk` like so:

```
milk: function( $elem ) {
    var isMilk = $elem.hasClass('milk');
    return (!isMilk?' ':'');
},
```

A jsfiddle is provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yvk9q/9/

**My problem:**

I am pulling the categories (classes or data-type) from a user generated database. For this reason I cannot simply add all the sorting variables to the code before hand.

I played with the fiddle and got a semi working sort here: http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/erfXH/1/ by using `data-category` instead of class. However,this just sorts all data alphabetically not by actual category.

**Some possible solutions:**

1. Use JSON to return an array of all categories and then use this to loop through classes
2. Use inline javascript and run a PHP loop inside a `<script>` tag
3. Write an external PHP file with a javascript header

**What I'm looking for**
The simplest best approach here, being if it's one of the solutions above or something different. This doesn't seem like it should need to be this complicated. So I may be over complicating this.

**EDIT:**

I now have a json array of my data but I can't figure out how to pass the data into the isotope settings when i try something like this

```
var $container = $('.sort-container');

var opts = {
    itemSelector: '.member-item',
    layoutMode: 'straightDown',
    getSortData : {
        $.getJSON( 'member-cat-json.php', function(data) { 
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var slug = data[i].slug;
                slug : function( $elem ) {
                    var is+slug = $elem.hasClass(slug);
                    return (!is+slug?' ':'');
                    }
                }
            }); 
        });
    }                                       
}

var $container = $('.sort-container');

$container.isotope(opts);
```

It fails because I can't use a loop inside of the plugin settings. Not sure what can be done about this though.

**EDIT 2:**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919827/isotope-dynamic-sorts) which seems about what I'm trying to do but unfortunately the [most recent jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sENdQ) fails with isotope

Here is a sample of my JSON output:

```
{term_id:9, name:Milk, slug:milk, term_group:0, term_taxonomy_id:17...}
{term_id:9, name:Eggs, slug:eggs, term_group:0, term_taxonomy_id:17...}
```

I am using the `slug` as the class name and in my loop.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You have JSON (as above), and you want to sort on a field: slug, in this case. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I'll state my assumptions and work from there:

- You have data in a format as described above:

  `{term_id:9, name:Milk, slug:milk, term_group:0, term_taxonomy_id:17...}`
- You want to sort on the `slug` names, even though we do not know what the slugs will be named ahead of time.

Assuming these two things, the fiddle you've linked to is close, but has a problem due to closures which [I have fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3r/DCRFf/1/).

As expected, your situation is similar to the one listed, except that you need to obtain the JSON data first, as you have.

```
var $container = $('.sort-container'),
    createSortFunction = function(slug) {
        return function($elem) {
            return $elem.hasClass(slug) ? ' ' : '';
        };
    }, 
    getSortData = function(data) {
        var sortMethods = {};

        for (var index in data) {
            var slug = data[index].slug;

            // immediately create the function to avoid
            // closure problems
            sortMethods[slug] = createSortFunction(slug);
        }

        return sortMethods;
    }

$.getJSON('member-cat-json.php', function (data) {
    // I'm wrapping the isotop creation inside the `getJSON`
    // call, just to ensure that we have `data`

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.member-item',
        layoutMode: 'straightDown',
        getSortData: getSortData(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You are on the right track. And understand my needs. But it looks like you have a few missing semicolons. I think I fixed them but something is wrong in `return sortMethods` I created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/788Ur/ (if you run JSHint you will see some errors)

Comment: I've correct the answer to remove JSHint problems (and included it as a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3r/svwxc/1/))

Comment: I am getting the javascript error `SyntaxError: missing variable name` which is defined as `for (var index in data) {` I am awarding you the bounty but really hope we can get this sorted out :)

Comment: Found the problem; there was a comma where there should have been a semi-colon in the `getSortData` function. Try again now.

Comment: Took a few more tweeks (actually no semi colon was required) here is the code I am now using: http://pastebin.com/ANPpyTdK